# Y-axis tick mark spacing is too close together. How do I space them out?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a line plot of 3-point makes for Steph so far this season but the spacing of the y axis ticks are way too close together.
[Line graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4r53.png) I'm sure there's a relatively easy fix for this. I'm also wondering how to label only Game 1 and Game 29 on the x-axis, rather than every single game. I hope this is enough information for an answer, if not let me know! Cheers.

```
ggplot(data=Top_10, aes(y=Stephen_Curry, x=Game_Number, group=1)) +
 geom_line(color="blue") +
 geom_point(color="black") +
 scale_x_discrete(limits = c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29")) +
 scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,15,1)) +
 theme(axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(r=5)))
```

Comment: Well it's not. You need to provide the data if you want a solution. Please, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any example data I could only guess what's the reason why the default scaling does not work.

However, based on this random example data set I was able to "replicate" your issue:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)

Top_10 <- data.frame(
  Game_Number = factor(1:30, levels = 1:30),
  Stephen_Curry = c(sample(0:15, 29, replace = TRUE), 100)
)

ggplot(data=Top_10, aes(y=Stephen_Curry, x=Game_Number, group=1)) +
  geom_line(color="blue") +
  geom_point(color="black") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = as.character(1:29)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,15,1)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(r=5)))
#> Warning: Removed 1 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

To solve this issue you could set limits of the y scale to `c(0, 15)` and for your x-axis issue you could set the breaks to `c("1", "29")`:

```r
ggplot(data=Top_10, aes(y=Stephen_Curry, x=Game_Number, group=1)) +
  geom_line(color="blue") +
  geom_point(color="black") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("1", "29"), limits = as.character(1:29)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,15,1), limits = c(0, 15)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(r=5)))
#> Warning: Removed 1 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).

#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]